# Boundaries of sets, (PDE Evans)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Im reading Evans PDE second edition.

In his appendix page 710 he gives the definition of a boundary $dU$  of an open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ as

---

A $dU$ is $C^{k}$ if for all $x^{0}$ $\in dU$ there exists $r>0$ and a $C^{k}$ function $\gamma:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that (upon relabelling and reorienting the coordinate axes if necessary) we have 
$$U\bigcap B(x^{0},r)=\{x\in B(x^{0},r) : x_{n}>\gamma(x_{1},...,x_{n-1}) \} $$

---

I have no intuition as to what these different boundaries could be like? What is special/useful about a boundary being $C^{1}$ , or $C^{k}$? Im really confused/lost with this definition. (Hopefully someone will include the relabelling and reorienting the coordinate axes in there answer? ) .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The point here is that a $C^{k}$ boundary can locally be described as the graph of a $C^{k}$ function in $n-1$ variables.

Comment: If you're familiar with manifolds, then all he's really saying is that $\mathrm{d}U$ is a $C^{k}$ boundary iff it is a $C^{k}$-differentiable manifold of dimension $n-1$.

Comment: Sadly have not studied manifolds;(